Dspace server oai throw ERROR unknown unknown org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter
In dspace 7.5, when I visit,
/server/oai/

I get this

but on dspace 8.0+ when I visit I get below error
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Nov 13 19:15:15 EST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/server/oai/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Even on sandbox dspace 9 https://sandbox.dspace.org/server/oai/ and demo 8 dspace I get this error. https://demo.dspace.org/server/oai/
Can you advise me on what setting and where to enable this to work?
and when I looked into the log files, I got this
    024-11-14 14:40:06,291 INFO  unknown 9ea2907f-7974-4b54-885e-150cf4b05c34 org.dspace.app.rest.utils.DSpaceAPIRequestLoggingFilter @ Before request [GET /server/oai/] originated from unknown
2024-11-14 14:40:06,296 ERROR unknown unknown org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter @ Forwarding to error page from request [/oai/] due to exception [Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/server/oai/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)]
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/server/oai/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:210) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1431) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1167) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:479) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapUnsecured$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:632) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:408) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:330) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:267) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1431) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1167) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:289) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.dspace.app.rest.filter.DSpaceRequestContextFilter.doFilter(DSpaceRequestContextFilter.java:41) ~[dspace-server-webapp-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.dspace.app.rest.filter.ContentLanguageHeaderResponseFilter.doFilter(ContentLanguageHeaderResponseFilter.java:51) ~[dspace-server-webapp-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:87) ~[dspace-services-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:479) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapUnsecured$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124) [spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99) [spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) [spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) [spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:173) [spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) [spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [catalina.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) [tomcat-util.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:10.1.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) [tomcat-util.jar:10.1.31]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) [?:?]

